On the martingale betting scheme
For a fixed probability $0 < p < 1$, let $X^p$ be the martingale that goes up by $1$ with probability $p$, and goes down by $\frac{p}{q}$ with probability $q := 1-p$.
Write $X$ for the deterministic process $X_t = t$.
Question: Does there exist a coupling of the $X^p$, and a deterministic subsequence $p_n \to 1$ such that $X^{p_n} \to X$ almost surely uniformly on compacts? That is, such that almost surely, for every $T > 0$,
$$\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |X_t^{p_n} - X_t| \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$.
Remark: The result may possibly be used to construct gambling schemes that provide guaranteed returns - at the cost of involving multiple people and funneling most of the risk of bankruptcy onto a few unlucky ones.

The following construction will do.
Let $U_1,U_2,\dots$ be independent random variables each uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Let $V^p_j:=1(U_j<p)-\frac pq\,1(U_j\ge p)$ for $j=1,2,\dots$. Finally, for $t=0,1,\dots$, let
$$X^p_t:=\sum_{j=1}^t V^p_j,$$
and take any sequence $(p_n)$ converging to $1$. Then all your conditions and the desired conclusion will hold.

Huh, it is surprising that it holds for any sequence $p_n$. Thanks for your answer!
